# Mostrar usuario que inicio sesion

Tags: php, html

Tengo un formulario para iniciar  sesion, lo que quiero es que al iniciar sesion me guarde el nombre del usuario para despues mostrarlo en un input en otro formulario

PHP

```
<?php  
   session_start();  
  include("conexion.php");
  
   try  
   {   
        $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostBD; dbname=$dataBD", $userBD, $passBD);  
        $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
        if(isset($_POST["login"]))  
        {  
             if(empty($_POST["usuario"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))  
             {  
                  $message = '<label>Todos los campos son requeridos</label>';  
             }  
             else  
             {  
                  $query = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password";  
                  $statement = $connect->prepare($query);  
                  $statement->execute(  
                       array(  
                            'usuario'     =>     $_POST["usuario"],  
                            'password'     =>     $_POST["password"]  
                       )  
                  );  
                  $count = $statement->rowCount();  
                  if($count > 0)  
                  {  
                       $_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["usuario"];  
                    
                       header("location:PanelControl.php");  
                  }  
                  else  
                  {  
                       $message = '<label>Datos incorrectos</label>';  
                  }  
             }  
        }  
   }  
   catch(PDOException $error)  
   {  
        $message = $error->getMessage();  
   }  
   ?>
```

HTML

```
<span>Usuario:</span>
        <input class="input"" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su Usuario" name="usuario">
        <span>Password:</span>
        <input class="input" type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su password" name="password">
        <br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn">Login</button>
```

Comment: En teoria ya lo tienes guardado en una variable de sesión cuando haces esto: `$_SESSION["usuario"] = $_POST["usuario"];` ... ¿que te impide usarlo en el formulario en el atributo value?  Debería funcionar a menos que ese formulario no sea generado por PHP y sea puro HTML

Comment: mi error era quererlo mostrar con echo en vez de print_r, MUCHAS GRACIAS POR LA AYUDA

Comment: mmm... no acabo de ver el sentido a tu comentario (no veo ningun echo en tu pregunta) pero bueno, si ya lo tienes claro me alegro por ti :-)  saludos!